# iPod touch debugging: Error on install/run only if app exists on device already?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am using an iPod to test an app. The device is all set up with the right provisioning profiles, etc-- that's not really the issue.

But every time I start the app from Xcode on the device, I get the "A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted." error from the Organizer window.

Wait, I know, you think it's a provisioning profile problem.

But here's the kicker: if I just delete the app from the iPod (using the main screen) and try again, it works fine. I only get this error when the app is already installed. The other kicker is that this behavior doesn't happen on an iPhone that I have for occasional testing-- on that device, I can start/restart/restart indefinitely. But using the iPod, my compile-run-test cycle is annoyingly slow since I have to manually delete the app each time.

Any ideas?

I'm using Xcode 3.2.2 (prerelease) FWIW. The iPod has stock OS 3.1.2 on it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with the original 3.2 beta 1 and my iPhone running 3.1.3. However, I did not need to delete my app to workaround it. I was able to get around it by using the clean all targets. It seems you've done that though. :(

That said, with the 3.2.2 beta 2: IDE 1643, Core 1644, ToolSupport 1631 - my problem went away.

From the release notes Beta 2:

FIXED: In iPhone SDK 3.2 beta 1, some users saw the message "A signed resource has been added, modified or deleted…" when rebuilding their projects. This has been fixed for beta 2.

Are you sure you're running Beta 2? Perhaps a re-install of xcode might help? I assume you've tried power cycling the iPod Touch?

Comment: Thanks for the tip on this, sckor-- upgraded to beta 2, problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can tell you is file a bug with apple [here](http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/) and hope they fix it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same ussue a couple of days ago. My problem was I had created a distribution build and installed it on my iPod through iTunes. After removing the app from iTunes and syncing the iPod Xcode stopped complaining when making new builds. 
Otherwise you could try "Clean all targets" under "Project" in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for the tips-- unfortunately I have never installed a distribution build of the app. I resynced anyways and cleaned all targets. No change. :\  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Also had this problem, try turning off the passcode lock: http://bencollier.net/2010/03/debugging-on-iphone-requires-app-deletion/